# solving equation for inverse transform sampling

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to generate pseudo random numbers from a distribution with distribution function $$F(x)= 1-1\exp(-ax+\frac{b}{p+1}x^{p+1})$$ In order to to that I need to solve the following equation for $y$

$$\log(1-u)= -ay-\frac{b}{p+1}y^{p+1}$$ for $p \in (0,1), a>0, b>0$

I would be glad if you could suggest a way to solve this equation.

Comment: Only numerical methods probably. it would be easy.

Comment: ok thank you! I tried it analytically and wasn`t sure whether I just don't know the trick